# Is it possible to view ProgressBar on Launching MainActivity?

Tags: android

Is it Possible to display first ProgressBar (intermediate) on Loading MainActivity . And hide the UI element Upto the ProgressBar is Visible.

I want to execute a method ( Internet check ) on my onCreate() method, And ProgressBar should be Visible upto method execute and also hide the Background UI elements.

Depends on method execute, i wil show the UI or make Dialog < No Internet >.

In short, My Question is , How can i display ProgressBar , and hide completely Main Layout UI ? Once the method execution over, progressBar will be off.

what i was trying to achieve is ,

```
 onCreate(...){

progressBar = (ProgressBar)find....
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

try{
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    boolean flag=isInternet();

    if(flag){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // start my app task
    }
}catch(..){
            Inflate my Dialog 
   }
}
```

But it is not working ..

Comment: why doing before main activity? Start a activity with content not visible, show you spinner, if internet connected, show your content

Comment: Murtaza Hussain @ am i clear enough ? I am working in single Activity - MainActivity. As soon as MainActivity.class will load, layout associated will be instantiated.

Comment: You are not aware of the concept of Android.  Maybe answer will help you,  although they are answering exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom interface to notify when no internet connectivity :

```
public interface WebCallListener{
  public void onCallComplete(String response);
  public void noInternetConnectivity();
}
```

Implement interface on web service call :

```
public void getDataFromServer(final WebCallListener webCallListener){
   if(isNetwokReachable()){
       new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){
          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
              //write your web service call code here
              return null;
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
               super.onPostExecute(response);
               webCallListener.onCallComplete(response);
          }
       }.execute();
   }else{
      webCallListener.noInternetConnectivity();
   }
}
```

Check internet connectivity :

```
public boolean isNetwokReachable() {
   final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   final NetworkInfo netInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

How to show/hide progress ;

```
pbrLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
getDataFromServer(new WebCallListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallComplete(String response) {
        pbrLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // parse data from response
    }
    @Override
    public void noInternetConnectivity() {
        pbrLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: method isNetwokReachable() always return true , whether Internet is available or Not. i am using bluestack.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `id` for your outer layout in your layout XML and use `findViewById`. Hide that layout when loading (all `View` within the layout will be hidden too) and show it when the loading is done.

```
parentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

boolean flag=isInternet();

if(flag){
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
// start my app task
parentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```